# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ERROR in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and trying to run a PS script using another PS script to run it as admin in Jenkins, the script gives its desired output but it also gives the error in the output.

> Powershell : Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found
>   that accepts argument  At line:4 char:1
>   + Powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell ""cd "F:\RiskLink\RiskL ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Start-Process :...cepts argument :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Code:

```
Set-Location -Path F:\abd\abc
$path = ".\xyz.ps1"
Powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell ""cd "F:\abd\abc"; & $path"" -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: Take the ampersand out

Comment: You did not double your quotes around `"F:\abd\abc"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago, I have created a simple command line parser (scripts `cliparser.ps1` and `cli parser.ps1`):

```
PS D:\PShell> Get-Content ".\cliparser.ps1"
    if ( $args -ne $null ) { $aLen=$args.Count } else { $aLen=0 }
    "$(Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf): $aLen parameters"
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $aLen ; $i++ ) { "{0}. [{1}]" -f $i, $args[$i] }
```

Used instead of yours `xyz.ps1`, it shows that something must go wrong not only with [`Start-Process` arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) but with quoting as well (shows supplied values `-Verb` and `RunAs`). Fixed with some little effort… Improved for space(s) in paths and file names, see the following script:

```
$cd = (Get-Location -PSProvider Filesystem).Path
$path = ".\cliparser.ps1"
'... original (known error)'
Write-Host Powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell ""pushd "$cd"; & $path"" -Verb RunAs"
Powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell ""pushd "$cd"; & $path"" -Verb RunAs"
pause
'... fixed'
Write-Host Powershell -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-noexit', '-command', 'pushd `'`'$cd`'`'; & `'`'$path`'`';' -Verb RunAs"
$path = ".\cli parser.ps1"
Powershell -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-noexit', '-command', 'pushd `'`'$cd`'`'; & `'`'$path`'`';' -Verb RunAs"
'done'
```

Note that PShell's parameters `-NoProfile` and `-NoExit` are here merely for debugging purposes.

**Result**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\53638416.ps1
... original (known error)
Powershell -Command Start-Process powershell "pushd  D:\PShell; & .\cliparser.ps1" -Verb RunAs
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'D:\PShell'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell pushd  D:\PShell; & .\cliparser.ps1 -Verb Ru ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Start
   ProcessCommand

cliparser.ps1: 2 parameters
0. [-Verb]
1. [RunAs]
Press Enter to continue...:
... fixed
Powershell -NoProfile -Command Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-noexit', '-command', 'pushd ''D:\PShell''; & ''.\cliparser.ps1'';' -Verb RunAs
done
PS D:\PShell>
```

Called (elevated) Powershell window looks as follows (`Pop-Location` used to ensure that `popd` ran well):

[image: administrator PShell]

To run from a `cmd` prompt and pass arguments to the called script:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-noexit', '-command', 'pushd ''D:\PShell''; & ''.\cliparser.ps1'' a b c;' -Verb RunAs"
```

[image]

Works for `pwsh` instead of `powershell` as well:

```
pwsh -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-noexit', '-command', 'pushd ''D:\PShell''; & ''.\cliparser.ps1'' a b c;' -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: Got this fixed. Thanks all for your assistance! Much appreciated!