# windows core run command with elevated privileges

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, administrator, powershell-core

There are a few options for standard user to run as Administrator (or any another user), however, even when logged as Administrator, some functions requires to run 'elevated'.

On a windows gui, just right click a `.exe` and select `run as Administrator` or even elevate 'cmd' or 'powershell'.

How can you get elevated privileges on Windows core?

Comment: You can find a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641894/3439404) to a similar question (runs using `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, to programmatically invoke an executable with elevation (Run as Administrator) on Windows, use the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet with  `-Verb RunAs`.

This applies equally to `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell *Core* executable, so that in the simplest case you can write:

```bash
# Open a new console window with PowerShell Core running with admin privileges.
Start-Process -Verb RunAs pwsh
```

---

If you wanted to wrap that in a **convenience function** that is also more robust and **cross-edition *on Windows*** (also works in Windows PowerShell):

- **Note**: See the bottom section for a more sophisticated function, downloadable from a Gist, which notably also allows passing *commands* to execute in the elevated PowerShell session.

```bash
function Enter-AdminPSSession {
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
}

# Optionally also define a short alias name:
# Note: 'psa' is a nonstandard alias name; a more conformant name would be
#       the somewhat clunky 'etasn' 
#       ('et' for 'Enter', 'a' for admin, and 'sn'` for session), analogous
#       to built-in 'etsn' alias referring to 'Enter-PSSession'
Set-Alias psa Enter-AdminPSSession
```

If you want the function to also be **cross-platform** (to also work on Unix-like platforms):

```bash
function Enter-AdminPSSession {
  if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
    Start-Process -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
  } else {
    sudo (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
  }
}
```

**Important**: Due to the cmdlets / utilities involved,

- on *Windows*, the new session invariably opens in a *new* console window.

  - The fact that the new session is an admin session is reflected in its window's title (prefix `Administrator:` )
- on *Unix* (Linux, macOS), the new session invariably opens in the *same* console (terminal) window.

  - On Unix there is no obvious indicator that an admin session has been entered; running `whoami` is a quick way to test for that (returns `root` in an admin session); a better solution would be to modify the `prompt` function to reflect an admin session in the prompt string, as the prepackage solution discussed next does.

---

If you additionally want **the ability to *run commands* in the new session and optionally auto-close it**, much more work is needed:

You **can download function `Enter-AdminPSSession` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/f726dee9f0d3d444bf58cb81fda57884)**, which:

- enables passing commands to execute via a script block (`{ ... }`)

  - keeps the session open by default, so that command output can be inspected, but you can opt-out with `-Exit` or `-ExitOnSuccess` (close the session only if no error occurred).
  - tries to reflect overall success of the commands passed via `$LASTEXITCODE` (even for PowerShell-native commands this variable is normally not set); `0` indicates success.
- ensures that the calling session's current location (working directory) is also the elevated session's current location.
- allows you to opt out of loading the profiles, with `-NoProfile`
- prefixes the prompt string in interactive elevated sessions with `[admin]` , on all platforms - except if [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/) is being used, which is assumed to use its own visualization to indicate the elevated status.

Assuming you have looked at the linked Gist's source code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can **install `Enter-AdminPSSession` directly as follows**:

```bash
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/f726dee9f0d3d444bf58cb81fda57884/raw/Enter-AdminPSSession.ps1 | iex
```

**Example calls** (which assume that `Set-Alias psa Enter-AdminPSSession` has been called):

- Enter an interactive elevated session:

```bash
psa
```

- Windows: Enter an elevated session without loading profiles and set the all-users execution policy, then exit if that succeeded.

```bash
psa -NoProfile -ExitOnSuccess { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine RemoteSigned }
```

- Unix: Gets the content of file `/etc/sudoers` (which can only be read with administrative privileges), then exits:

```bash
psa -Exit { Get-Content /etc/sudoers }
```