# How to start another PowerShell session in a separate window while keeping the environment?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

While working in PowerShell I tend to quickly switch to admin mode by typing

```
Start-Process wt -Verb runas
```

When I do so, a new window appears (sadly, no `sudo` in Windows). In that new session however, the environment is totally fresh. Is it possible to keep variables, aliases, working dir and all other stuff of similar matter while jumping to a new window? If not, then well, it's a valid answer.

---

To give some example, I am looking for this behavior:

##### First window

```
C:\test> $x = 123
C:\test> Start-Process wt
```

##### New window

```
C:\test> $x
123
```

Comment: In PowerShell there's a difference between environment variables and general-purpose variables. If you do `$env:x = "123"` and then subsequently launch a child process, it'll inherit `$env:x`

Comment: I wasn't sure. Then I would like to keep both.

Comment: As I checked now, `$env:x` is not preserved when creating a new window. Maybe it is not a child at all?

Comment: _Environment_ variables are inherited by child processes _except_ when `-Verb RunAs` is used, by design. _Regular_ variables are _never_ inherited by child processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By (security-minded) design, *elevated* sessions (`-Verb RunAs`) do *not* inherit the caller's *environment variables*.

Also, wether or not you use `-Verb RunAs`, the state of a *PowerShell* session (aliases, functions, current location, ...) is *never* inherited when you launch another PowerShell process, such as with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process).

---

You can work around the issue by explicitly and selectively redefining the state of interest via commands executed in the elevated session, based on values from the caller's state, but that is quite cumbersome and has limitations, as the following example shows:

```
# Define a few things to copy to the elevated session.
$x1 = 123
$x2 = '3" of snow' # !! See the caveat re regular variables below.
$env:foo = 1
$env:foo2 = 2
Set-Alias bar Get-Date
function baz { "hello, world" }

# Note: The following only copies the definitions above.
#       You could try to copy ALL such definitions, by omitting a target name / pattern:
#         Get-ChildItem env:
#         Get-ChildItem function:
#         Get-ChildItem alias:
#       CAVEAT: This will NOT generally work with *regular variables*.
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell @"
-NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath \"$((Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath)\"
$(Get-Variable x? | ForEach-Object { "`${$($_.Name)} = $(if ($_.Value -is [string]) { "'{0}'" -f ($_.Value -replace "'", "''" -replace '"', '\"')  } else { $_.Value }); " })
$(Get-ChildItem env:foo* | ForEach-Object { "Set-Item \`"env:$($_.Name)\`" \`"$($_.Value -replace '"', '\"\"')\`"; " })
$(Get-ChildItem function:bar | ForEach-Object { "`$function:$($_.Name) = \`"$($_.Definition -replace '"', '\"\"')\`"; " })
$(Get-ChildItem alias:baz | ForEach-Object { "`$alias:$($_.Name) = \`"$($_.Definition)\`"; " })
"@
```

**Important**:

- I've omitted the call to Windows Terminal (`wt.exe`), as that would create *another* PowerShell session, which means that only the following definitions would be preserved for *that* session:

  - Environment variables.
  - The current location (working directory), *IF* its default shell is configured to use the parent process' working directory. Alternatively, and more predictably, pass the working dir. explicitly with the `-d` option: 
    `wt.exe -d \"$((Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath)\"`
  - If that is enough, you can remove the commands that preserve aliases, functions, and regular variables, add `-WindowStyle Hidden` to `Start-Process`, remove `-NoExit`  before `-Command` in the argument list, and add a `wt.exe` call at the bottom.
- Preserving the other types of definitions requires working directly in the elevated `powershell` session, which will invariably use a *regular* (`conhost.exe`) console window, however.

In general, it's best to place definitions that should be available in both regular and elevated sessions in your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles).

Complementarily, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199970/45375) for convenience function `Enter-AdminPSSession`, which allows you to pass a script block to execute in the elevated session, to which you can pass values from the caller's state as arguments.

Note:

- The above uses the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, `powershell.exe`. To use *PowerShell (Core) 7+* instead, substitute `pwsh.exe`.
- The above covers preserving the current *file-system* location, environment variables, aliases, and functions in a *generic* fashion.
- **Caveat**: By contrast, preserving *regular* variables is limited to *strings and numbers* - in essence, instances of those data types whose stringified representation is recognized as such when interpreted as a source-code literal.

  - With nontrivial additional effort, supporting more data types is possible, by using Base64 encoding with the CLI's `-EncodedCommand` and `-EncodedArguments` parameters as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986341/45375), but the range of types that can be represented with type fidelity is fundamentally limited by PowerShell's XML-based serialization infrastructure - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

Answer (score -1):

You can not keep variables, you will lose them immediately after the new window is created, the best you can do instead is to create a script containing all your activities then save it in the same working directory.

When you open a new window just call your script that will be able to give you the same information as in the other window.